async version of Context.run for context vars in python asyncio?
Python has the contextvars.copy_context() function which lets you store a copy of the current values of all the ContextVars that are currently active. Then later, you can run with all those values active by calling context_returned_by_copy_context.run(func). However, the run method is sync and expects a regular callable, not an async one. How can you run an async function with a context returned by copy_context?

Your problem is "How to execute async code from sync context". There are two options: 1. Create a new event loop which executes an async function (as task). 2. Append the async function (as task) to an already running event loop.

@lord_haffi I'm aware of that general issue, but I figured in this specific case there must be some common work around since a big point of using ContextVar is they work in async functions, and the appeal of copy_context would (I thought?) primarily be running a task with the context from another task; it seems like a weird oversight

Well yes, but ContextVars are not specific for usage with async functions. They are also widely used with multi-threading or multi-processing. Further, I don't think there is a common workaround for this as it highly depends on where you are running the context object. E.g. if you are executing context_returned_by_copy_context.run(func) from within a running event loop, you'd have to add it to the event loop. If not, you'd have to create a new one. But these two cases behave differently. So I don't think that this has a "general" solution.

I have my answer bellow, but TL:DR; just wrap a coroutine awaiting in a task: all tasks run in separate contexts than the place where they are created - one doesn' t have to ever call context_copy explicitly.

lord_haffi's suggestion is apropos, but there is no need to create a new event loop since one should already be running:
import asyncio
import contextvars

x = contextvars.ContextVar('x')

async def async_fn():
    """An aysnc coroutine we would like to run with contextvars.Contex.run"""

    print(x.get())

def fn():
    """ A non-coroutine that we will run with contextvars.Context.run"""

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return loop.create_task(async_fn())

async def demo(value):
    x.set(value)
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    await ctx.run(fn)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(demo(1), demo(2))

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
1
2


Generally I agree with you but I wouldn't say that there is always a running event loop. You could combine use cases multi-threading and multi-processing with asyncio. As a matter of fact, I recently implemented a FastAPI server using multiprocessing and asyncio for an endpoint as it creates both a CPU and network heavy task plus I needed to "unblock" the FastAPI event loop. But the event loop in each process is then only created at a certain point when the network heavy part starts. Just as an example :)

@lord_haffi I didn't say or even imply that an event loop is always running in general. I said one should already be running based on this specific situation where a non-coroutine is being invoked from a coroutine (for which there must be a running loop).

Well, I wasn't sure if the OP was executing it from a coroutine. Would make a lot of sense though based on how the question was asked. If it's the case, then you're absolutely right of course.

This is pretty close to what I ended up doing

The reason this works at all is because when one create a task, and doesn't await directly for it (in this case, the demo co-routines are wrapped as tasks inside the .gather code), asyncio automatically starts a task with its own copy of the current context.

The asyncio framework is really friendly to contextvars, and actually the later had been created in the language due to needs arising from asynchronous workflows.
Usually, there is no need to manually copy a context and then call context.run  in some async workflow - since Python 3.10, most of the callables to create a task will take the context keyword parameter. Just pass in your context copy there. In the event you want to call and await a simple co-routine, wrap it in a task to do so - the loop.create_task call takes in a context parameter, which allows a task to run in a explictly passed context - but otherwise a task will simply run in a fresh copy of the current context.
import asyncio, contextvars

myvar = contextvars.ContextVar("aa")

async def mycoroutine():
     myvar.set("internal value")
     print(myvar.get())

async def mycode():
    myvar.set("outer value")
    ...
    await asyncio.create_task(mycoroutine()))  
    # here if one wishes to coordinate several of these tasks
    # running in the same context, they can pass the optional 
    # create_task(coro, context=ctx) argument. Otherwise a fresh copy
    # is created and used in the task.
    print(myvar.get())
    

asyncio.run(mycode)

